# How to turn 2 tier accordion into 3 tier accordion

Tags: html

I am trying to turn a 2 tier accordion into a 3 tier one but this code is quite confusing. Any assistance would be appreciated. Clicking on the first tier and second tier does exactly the same thing and it's to do with the naming obviously but I can't seem to get it right.

```
<div class="m-accordion m-accordion--bordered" id="m_accordion_2" role="tablist">
    <div class="m-accordion__item">
        <div class="m-accordion__item-head" role="tab" id="m_accordion_2_item_1_head" data-toggle="collapse" href="#m_accordion_2_item_1_body" aria-expanded="true">
            <span class="m-accordion__item-icon">
                <i class="fa flaticon-user-ok"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="m-accordion__item-title">
                First Tier
            </span>
            <span class="m-accordion__item-mode"></span>
        </div>
    <div class="m-accordion__item-body collapse show" id="m_accordion_2_item_1_body" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="m_accordion_2_item_1_head" data-parent="#m_accordion_2" style="">
            <div class="m-accordion__item-content">
        <div class="m-accordion__item-head" role="tab" id="m_accordion_2_item_1_head" data-toggle="collapse" href="#m_accordion_2_item_1_body" aria-expanded="true">
            <span class="m-accordion__item-icon">
                <i class="fa flaticon-user-ok"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="m-accordion__item-title">
                Second Tier
            </span>
            <span class="m-accordion__item-mode"></span>
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="m-accordion__item-body collapse show" id="m_accordion_2_item_1_body" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="m_accordion_2_item_1_head" data-parent="#m_accordion_2" style="">
            <div class="m-accordion__item-content">
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the original code for 2 tiers only:

```
<div class="m-accordion m-accordion--bordered" id="m_accordion_2" role="tablist">
    <div class="m-accordion__item">
        <div class="m-accordion__item-head" role="tab" id="m_accordion_2_item_1_head" data-toggle="collapse" href="#m_accordion_2_item_1_body" aria-expanded="true">
            <span class="m-accordion__item-icon">
                <i class="fa flaticon-user-ok"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="m-accordion__item-title">
                When an unknown printer took
            </span>
            <span class="m-accordion__item-mode"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="m-accordion__item-body collapse show" id="m_accordion_2_item_1_body" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="m_accordion_2_item_1_head" data-parent="#m_accordion_2" style="">
            <div class="m-accordion__item-content">
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you mean to wrap most of your code in <div class="m-accordion__item"> on line 2?
If not, you have a </div> too many in the bottom - not sure if that solves anything though

Comment: I have updated my original question to show the original 2 tier code if that helps. I want the first head to contain a second head and the body inside the second head.

Answer (score 1):

I know you're not meant to put picture of code here, but it's the best way to visualize this problem.

[image]

Essentially, each expandable section has 2 attributes that need to line up between the title (the part that always visible) and the body (the part that expands when you click the title). Everything else can stay the same from panel to panel, but these two attribute need to match between the header and the body, AND they need to be unique for every individual collapsed panel.

So you could have 3 panels, with their Id's being:

Panel 1: `id="m_accordion_2_item_1_body"`

Panel 2: `id="m_accordion_2_item_2_body"`

Panel 3: `id="m_accordion_2_item_3_body"`

Read the bootstrap docs carefully, since you are using data-attributes to control this.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/#via-data-attributes